# How to add more ticks to a ggplot timeseries with timestamps

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I visualized a timeseries as line graph by using ggplot. However, I would like to have more ticks on the x-axis.

The timestamp is the following format: 2014-01-10 00:30:00

```
p3 <- ggplot(sub2, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Value)) +
  geom_line( color="#2a7a3f") + 
  xlab("Time")+
  ylab("Chloride")
  
# Title
p3 + labs(title = "Chloride Concentration over Time") + theme_minimal() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=11, face='bold')) 

``
```

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow does not allow uploads of pictures right now.

Comment: When I create subset of 30days I got only 2 x-axis labels with days.

Comment: I don't know the time frame you're looking at, but perhaps you could specify like `+ scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 hour", date_labels = "%d %H%p")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `pretty_breaks` from `scales` to easily alter the number of breaks (although it is not exactly the number you specify)

use it like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris
df$rand_date <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct('2017/05/01'), as.POSIXct('2017/05/02'), by="1 mins"), 150)


ggplot(data = df, aes(x = rand_date, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n=5),date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

the `n`-parameter controls the number of breaks you'll get on the plot

Comment: + library(scales)

Comment: yes, if you load the library you can change `scales::pretty_breaks(n=5)` to `pretty_breaks(n=5)`